# Creating a gui to unlock locked accounts

Tags: xaml, powershell

So Starting off small i want to find an IP address if an account has been logged out on my servers, I've made the GUI, its fine but the button doesn't work, any idea where I've gone wrong?

in theory it should return a string which contains an IP address, a time stamp and a date but i'm new to power shell so i'm not really 100% sure what i'm doing, any help would be appreciated

```
inputXML = @"
<Window x:Class="UnlockerGui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="538.433">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="538" Margin="0,0,-8,-21" RenderTransformOrigin="0.295,0.552">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="101*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="239*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BtnSearch" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="271" Height="45"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="LbResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="246" Margin="10,60,0,0" Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="504"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML
 $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
  try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."}
 #===========================================================================
# Load XAML Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

Function Get-FormVariables{
if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
get-variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables

#===========================================================================
# Actually make the objects work
#===========================================================================

#Sample entry of how to add data to a field

#$vmpicklistView.items.Add([pscustomobject]@{'VMName'=($_).Name;Status=$_.Status;Other="Yes"})

Function Get-Data{
param([string]$Localusername)
string[] $results1 =  
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName SERVERNAME1 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
Select-Object -Property timecreated,
@{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}


foreach($string in $results1)
{
     $WPFLbResults.Items.Add($results1[$string])
}

string[] $results2 =  
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName SERVERNAME2 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
Select-Object -Property timecreated,
@{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}

foreach($string in $results2)
{
     $WPFLbResults.Items.Add($results2[$string])
}

string[] $results3 =  
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName SERVERNAME3 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
Select-Object -Property timecreated,
@{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}

foreach($string in $results3)
{
     $WPFLbResults.Items.Add($results3[$string])
}

}

#===========================================================================
# Shows the form
#===========================================================================

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$WPFBtnSearch.Add_Click({
$username = $WPFTxtName.Text
Get-Data($username)
})
```

Comment: `$WPFBtnSearch` is not defined anywhere, and even if it were, you'd need to call `add_Click()` *before* invoking `$Form.ShowDialog()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it's in the xaml at the top, is that not right?

Comment: You're right, it is - in which case, please follow my second suggestion

Comment: The XAML at the top has `BtnSearch` rather than `WPFBtnSearch`

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!! Thankyou, i appreciate it, been trying to figure this out for ages now!